# Why Flask is not rendering the html page using code below?

Tags: python, html, amazon-web-services, flask, cloud9

I started up a new project on `AWS C9` platform and i have a problem with rendering a web page with the framework Flask

The framework runs properly it can return messages (by default) but when i try to return a template(Html page) i receive the error: "TemplateNotFound"
I will leave the code below and the error messages

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('templates/home.html')

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return "<h1>Flask is working</h1>"    


if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
    app.debug = True
```

Stack trace:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2311, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1834, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1737, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1832, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1818, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ec2-user/environment/Flask_Catalog/flaskCatalog.py", line 10, in home
    return render_template('templates/home.html')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 134, in render_template
    return _render(ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 869, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 830, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 113, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 58, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 86, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
TemplateNotFound: templates/home.html



LicentaCatalogOnline2019
 |
 +--Flask_Catalog
 |  |  
 |  +-- flaskCatalog.py
 |    
 +--templates
 |  |  
 |  +-- about.html
 |  +-- home.html
```

Comment: maybe check with functions from module os whether the path you defined for the templates exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default flask looks for html templates in `templates` folder. You dont need to explicitly append `/templates` in your return statement.

Use this

`return render_template('home.html')`

Comment: Can you post your directory structure.

Comment: Templates folder should be in root folder of your main flask py file. So move templates folder into flask_catalog

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this platform. i voted up your answer. This is what you mean ?